# PHP PDO - The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION

Tags: sql-server, php, transactions, freetds

While inserting into MSSQL using PHP PDO Dblib I am having this error

> exit signal Segmentation fault in apache error log

When I checked the free tds log the error is

> The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION

However this is happening for a particular case only that is when I have string for a float data type. Below is my code:

```
$conn = new PDO('dblib:host=hostname;dbname=mydbname', 'user', 'password');
$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$conn->beginTransaction();
$query = 'INSERT INTO [TestTable] ([RecordNo], [Paymode], [VATVALUE])
          VALUES (:RecordNo, :Paymode, :VATVALUE)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
try {
    $stmt->execute( [":VATVALUE" => "158.4'", ":Paymode" => "CREDIT", 
                                    ":RecordNo" => "ABC-312735"] );
    $conn->commit();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $conn->rollback();
}
```

Please note the vat value which I have set it as

> 158.4'

for replicating the error. However when I remove the transaction statements then it is throwing the proper error i.e.

> Error converting data type varchar to float

Interestingly the beginTransaction() is working perfectly if I specify a wrong column name in the statement. The transaction is not working only for this conversion error and throwing signal segmentation fault error.

I am using PHP 7.0 in ubuntu 16.04. Wondering why rollback working fine in all cases like wrong column names or table name but not in the conversion case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are errors in SQL Server which will automatically roll back your transaction, and it's an error to attempt a rollback after that.  Instead of

```
$conn->rollback();
```

try executing the batch

```
if @@trancount>0 rollback;
```

I don't know PHP but perhaps something like:

```
$conn->prepare("if @@trancount>0 rollback;")->execute();
```

Comment: You are right..this solution is working fine. It seems the issue is with pdo dblib which is not able to handle this kind of error. I changed the code to use the raw query instead of beginTransaction().